# SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.attribute_set_id'

Tags: magento2, database, collection, product-collection, attribute-set

I am trying to Filter the products based on **vendorid** with **attribute_set_id**.
if i use **print_r** in the collection i am getting the result like below

```
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $productCollectionFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
    $collection = $productCollectionFactory
        ->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter('vendor_id', $vendorId)
        ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', array('neq' => '11'))
        ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', array('neq' => '12'))
        ->load();

     echo "<pre>";print_r($collection->getData());exit();
```

Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [entity_id] => 508
            [attribute_set_id] => 4
            [type_id] => simple
            [sku] => simple-shop4-1
            [has_options] => 0
            [required_options] => 0
            [created_at] => 2019-08-29 09:46:36
            [updated_at] => 2019-08-29 09:46:36
            [vendor_id] => 36
            [is_salable] => 1
        )

)
```

The above result is true. but when i execute i am getting the below error like

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'e.attribute_set_id' in 'where clause', query was: SELECT
>   FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 10) + 1 AS `range`, COUNT(*) AS
>   `count` FROM `catalog_product_index_price` AS `e`  INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `at_vendor_id` ON
>   (`at_vendor_id`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND
>   (`at_vendor_id`.`attribute_id` = '166') AND (`at_vendor_id`.`store_id`
>   = 0)  INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id 
>   INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index_store1` AS `cat_index` ON
>   cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND
>   cat_index.visibility IN(2, 4) AND cat_index.category_id=2 WHERE
>   (at_vendor_id.value = '36') AND (`e`.`attribute_set_id` != '11') AND
>   (`e`.`attribute_set_id` != '12') AND (stock_status_index.stock_status
>   = 1) AND (at_vendor_id.value = '36') AND ( e.website_id = '1' ) AND ( e.customer_group_id = 0) AND (e.min_price IS NOT NULL) GROUP BY
>   FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 10) + 1 ORDER BY
>   (FLOOR((ROUND((e.min_price) * 1, 2)) / 10) + 1) ASC

Anyone have any idea about this.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It seems to be indexing issue. 
Perform full re-indexing and flush cache.

Comment: @SavanPatel Thanks for your response. But the issue still persists after reindexing also.